# Test IHttpActionResult with ExecuteAsync through controller

Tags: c#, .net, testing, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

**In short:** What's the best way to test a IHttpActionResult through the controller in unit tests?

---

Given a custom `IHttpActionResult` with some logic in the `ExecuteAsync` method

```
public class AcceptedResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    private readonly Func<string> _ticket;

    public AcceptedResultV2(HttpRequestMessage request, Func<string> ticket)
    {
        _ticket = ticket;
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
        response.Headers.Add("x-ticket-id", _ticket());
        return response;
    }
}
```

and a controller method who exposes a `IHttpActionResult`

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Get(SearchScheduledTaskRequest searchScheduledTaskRequest)
{
    if(something) return new AcceptedResult(Request, () => "foo");
    return new AcceptedResult(Request, () => "bar");
}
```

What is the best way to test this?

At the moment, I've settled for calling `ExecuteAsync` manually, but it's a bit of a bummer I have to always call `ExecuteAsync`.

I could of course extract it somewhere, but **I'm wondering if there is a better way.**

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Has_Request_Id()
    {
        var response = await _controller.Get(new SearchScheduledTaskRequest()).ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken.None);

        System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> headers;
        response.Headers.TryGetValues("x-request-id", out headers);
        Assert.AreEqual("foo", headers.First());
    }
```

**Update:** made it more clear that I want to test if the controller returns a response with a certain header.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the provided code, I'd just test if the **ExecuteAsync** method of the **AcceptedResult** class returns a response containing the correct headers, because that should always be the case.

Your controller test method just needs to verify whether the result matches the **AcceptedResult** type.

Comment: Sure, but that way it's not possible to test that a Controller returns a response with a certain header. Updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: You're going to need the response to see if the headers have been set, which ultimately means that the result needs to be executed. So I don't think there are shortcuts to achieve this.